# What is Rails way to DRY up the controller pattern of verifying :id is for a valid object (else redirect to error page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

One of my controllers has close to 100 methods (eg routes) and nearly every one starts out the same code to redirect to an error page if the id param is invalid, followed by a similar check if the user that id doesn't belong in the user's account:

```
def something
  @foo = Foo.find_by_guid(params[:id])
  unless @foo
    @msg ||= { :title => 'No such page!',
      :desc => "There is no such page!" }
    render :action => "error" and return
  end
  unless @foo.owner_id == current_user.id
   @msg ||= { :title => 'Really?',
      :desc => "There is no such page." }
    render :action => "error" and return
  end
```

What is the best way to DRY up that sort of page id and owner id validation, given the code is doing a render ... and return?

What I don't want to do at this point is offload it to a blackbox roles and permissions library like CanCan... my goal is simply to have the in-app code to handle this be as clean as possible.

Comment: `current_user.foos.find_by_guid!(params[:id])` restricts the lookup to the user's stuff (assuming the has_many association is set up) and raises an exception if one is not found. By the way, "close to 100 methods" suggests this is a Very Bad Design™.

Comment: well, it has 100 different views and does 100 different things ;) thx for the tip re current_user!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need a before filter:

```
class MegaController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :grab_and_check_foo
    #...
private
    def grab_and_check_foo
        @foo = Foo.find_by_guid(params[:id])
        if !@foo
            #... render some error stuff
        end
        if @foo.owner_id != current_user.id
            #... render some other error stuff
        end
    end
end
```

A [before-filter can break out of the usual controller process](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) by redirecting or rendering something so that's not a problem.

Comment: The missing piece of the puzzle for me was that before_filter can have :except => [:meth1, :meth2], since, as i noted, 'almost' every method needed it.

Comment: @jpwynn: There's also `skip_filter` but that's more useful if a base class is adding the filter.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a before filter to check the ownership and render or redirect base on the check